# Why does Textify.js only work in HTML and not in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add [Textify.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/textify.js) to a site. But something is not working correctly. I only see animation when I change my code. But if I try to reload, change page (react-router) etc ... nothing happens.

I have tried with HTML and everything works fine.

I'm not very good with Js / React ...

Thanks.

```js
import Textify from "textify.js";

new Textify();

export function Home() {
  return (
<Container>

  <p data-textify>
    Some cool text.
  </p>

</Container>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The library is not compatible with react

Comment: now, textify js is support all environment and also capable to work in SSR or next.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is incompatible with react.

The right way of using it is to initialize it in useEffect after the component has finished rendering on the DOM.

```
import Textify from "textify.js";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    new Textify();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p data-textify>Some cool text.</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```